# Validate XML value input in Qt?

Tags: xml, qt, validation, qlineedit

I would like to avoid code injections, so I subclassed a QValidator for check, if string in QLineEdit does not contain "dangerous" chars f.e. <,>,&,",'.
Is there any simpler way to validate input from given string? 
Thank you for your tips.

*myvalidator.h*

```
extern class cXMLValueValidator : public QValidator{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  explicit cXMLValueValidator(QObject *parent = 0);
  virtual State validate(QString & input, int & pos) const;
};
```

*myvalidator.cpp*

```
QValidator::State cXMLValueValidator::validate(QString & input, int & pos) const {
  if(input.isEmpty())
      return Acceptable;
    if(input.contains(QRegExp("[<>&\"\']")))
      return Invalid;
  return Acceptable;
}
```

Implementation:

```
QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
lineEdit->setValidator(new cXMLValueValidator(lineEdit));
```

Comment: You might validate input by handling `QLineEdit::textChanged()` signal, for example.

Comment: I don't think so, but there are only two characters you have to escape: `<` and `&` (for element content). So why not just do that?

Comment: SteakOverflow: I found 5 chars <,>,&,", ' which can corrupt your xml.

Comment: You can but you don't have to escape those. Still a very limited set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. There is no other way to validate xml input except your own QValidator.